# Where to get access to oil and gas wells data with its production level? and Earthquake datasets?

Tags: data

i been trying to look for oil and gas well data (specifically in excel format) which contains the level of production as well. Where can i also get access to earthquake dataset? I looked on usgs already but do not know how to access it

Comment: earthquake data? like you want to map earthquake locations??

Comment: Best place to ask is: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i have a script that extracts the USGS earthquake and creates a feature class. if you have arcpy...please give more info

Comment: We have written a set of R scripts that web-scrub oil-gas well data, using CURL, for each state that makes it available. There are several states that you have to submit a written request or locks it down entirely (eg., Texas). I would note that there are HUGE issues with the state-level data in regard to attributes. There is no way that you are getting a hold of production data. This is proprietary data and indicates a companies financials so, is closely guarded. The best data out there is the commercial IHS well data but it is very expensive.

Comment: Yes i want to map earthquake locations in the USA, specifically a state-level data, I think i am more interested in mapping earthquake data in CA

Answer (score 3):

not sure exactly your question but I wrote this script a while back. All you would have to do is change your gdb path name and this script will spit out a feature class of USGS recorded earthquakes.

if you go to this link, you can plug in any of the geojson formatted USGS earthquake links and just pass it through my script

https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php

```
#This script scrapes GeoJSON data of earthquake incidents from the USGS website and creates a ESRI feature class. 
import urllib2
import json
import arcpy
from datetime import datetime
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
def GeoJSONToFC(gdb,USGSurl,fcname):
    geodb = gdb
    earthq = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(geodb,fcname,"POINT",'','',"ENABLED",4326)
    arcpy.AddField_management(earthq,"Place","TEXT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(earthq, "Magnitude", "FLOAT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(earthq, "KM_From_Place", "SHORT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(earthq, "Bearing", "TEXT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(earthq, "Date", "TEXT")
    url = USGSurl
    weburl = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    if weburl.getcode() == 200:
        data = json.loads(weburl.read())
    for i in data["features"]:
        place = ""
        mag = i["properties"]["mag"]
        p1 = i["properties"]["place"].split()
        p2 = ''.join(c for c in p1[0] if c not in 'km')
        km = ''.join(z for z in p2 if z.isdigit())
        bear = ''.join(b for b in p1[1] if b in ('S','SSE','SE','ESE','E','ENE','NE','NNE','N','NNW','NW','WNW','W','WSW','SW','SSW'))
        if type(km) == str: km = None
        else: km = int(str(km))
        if type(bear) == str: bear = None
        if bear == None and km == None: place = i["properties"]["place"]
        else: place = ' '.join(i["properties"]["place"].split()[3:])
        time = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(i["properties"]["time"])/1000))[0:10]
        point = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(float(i["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]),float(i["geometry"]["coordinates"][1])),arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
        print place, mag, km, bear
        with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(earthq,["Place","Magnitude","KM_From_Place","Bearing","Date","SHAPE@"]) as cur:
            row = (place,mag,km,bear,time,point)
            cur.insertRow(row)
            print row

gdb = r"path\quakes.gdb"
url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson"
name = "MajorQuakes"
GeoJSONToFC(gdb,url,name)
```